# What's the downside of using global mongo (mgo) database in golang?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

**Are there** any downsides if we use a global variable to handle database operations instead of passing it as an argument to functions and methods or storing it as a field in structs?

**What are these downsides (if there are)?**

Let's say we create a package inside a project called database, inside that package define a variable called DB `var DB *mgo.Database`, and then in project's main function fill it with our mongo database:

```
func main() {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    database.DB = session.DB("mydatabase")
    // project code
    defer session.Close()
}
```

After that, we use database.DB to interact with our database.

**Note that there will be lots of goroutines using database.DB (if it makes any difference)**

**The question is not opinion based, please take more time to read and understand**

**I REPEAT AGAIN The question is not opinion based, please take more more time to read and understand**

Comment: I disagree with the votes to close, as the answer to that question is _not_ opinion based, but because there are empirical drawbacks of _just_ using `database.DB` for the interaction with the database, namely nor using the underlying connection pool.

Comment: It's not opinion based obviously, it's about performance. I am really sorry for stackoverflow community. Thanks @MarkusWMahlberg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure of using a globally initialized database to be handed down to the places it is needed is well established and reasonable.

However, *just* using `database.DB` in a manner like

```
_ = database.DB.C(foo).Find(q).One(&bar)
```

all over the place holds a significant disadvantage: you only use one connection of the underlying connection pool, practically ensuring that *all* requests are processed sequentially.

So what you rather want to do is something like this:

```
s := database.DB.Session.Copy()
_ = database.DB.C(foo).With(s).Find(q).One(&bar)
defer s.Close()
```

for „parallel“ requests (there are some caveats about parallel requests, which I leave out for the sake of brevity).

Comment: thanks, as simple as that.